# How to mutate a new column by modifying another column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have very simple question.
I have a df like,

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3))
```

I want to add a new column by adding 'z000' to existing id by using 'mutate' function of dplyr, 
My expectation is like,

```
df2 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3),new_id=c("z0001","z0002","z0003"))
```

Please let me know how to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need `paste0`

```
df1 %>% 
mutate(new_id = paste0("z000", id))

  id new_id
1  1 z0001
2  2 z0002
3  3 z0003
```