# R: How to assign new 4 digits ID by adding previous ID

Tags: r, dplyr, assign

I saw the question ([How to mutate a new column by modifying another column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60638082/how-to-mutate-a-new-column-by-modifying-another-column)).

I have similar problem, but I want assign 5 digits ID, like

```
df2 <- data.frame(id=c(1,10,100),new_id=c("z0001","z0010","z0100"))
```

from

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,10,100))
```

Please tell me the way to do so instead of just pasting 'z000'.

Comment: Why you don't like the paste solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stringr` can do what you want:

```
library(stringr)
df1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,10,100))

df1$new_id <- str_c("z", str_pad(df1$id, 4, pad = "0"))
df1
```

Comment: This is what I want to do. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In base R, we can use `sprintf` with `paste0`

```
df1$new_id <- paste0('z', sprintf('%04d', df1$id))
df1

#   id new_id
#1   1  z0001
#2  10  z0010
#3 100  z0100
```