# R: How to mutate new ID by modifying previous ID?

Tags: r, string

I asked the question([How to mutate a new column by modifying another column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60638082/how-to-mutate-a-new-column-by-modifying-another-column))

Now I have another problem. I have to use more 'untidy'IDs like,

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c("A-1","A-10","A-100","b-1","b-10","b-100"),n=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

from this IDs, I want to assign new 'tidy' IDs like,

```
df2 <- data.frame(id=c("A0001","A0010","A0100","B0001","B0010","B0100"),n=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

(now I need capital 'B' instead of 'b')

I tried to use str_pad functiuon, but I couldn't manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can separate the data into different columns based on `"-"`, convert the letters to uppercase, using `sprintf` pad with 0's and combine the two columns with `unite`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  separate(id, c("id1", "id2"), sep = "-") %>%
  mutate(id1 = toupper(id1), 
         id2 = sprintf('%04s', id2)) %>%
  unite(id, id1, id2, sep = "")

#     id n
#1 A0001 1
#2 A0010 2
#3 A0100 3
#4 B0001 4
#5 B0010 5
#6 B0100 6
```

---

Based on the comment if there are cases where we don't have separator and we want to change certain `id1` values we can use the following.

```
df1 %>%
  extract(id, c("id1", "id2"), regex = "([:alpha:])-?(\\d+)") %>%
  mutate(id1 = case_when(id1 == 'c' ~ 'B', 
                         TRUE ~ id1), 
         id1 = toupper(id1),id2 = sprintf('%04s', id2)) %>%
  unite(id, id1, id2, sep = "")
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak. It works for me. Just in case if I want to convert "c1" to "B0001", how can I do that? (Now I don't have "-" and want to change character)

Comment: @tantan Updated the answer on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The `str_pad` function is handy for this purpose, as you said. But you have to extract out the digits first and then paste it all back together.

```
library(stringr)

paste0(toupper(str_extract(df1$id, "[aA-zZ]-")), 
      str_pad(str_extract(df1$id, "\\d+"), width=4, pad="0"))

[1] "A-0001" "A-0010" "A-0100" "B-0001" "B-0010" "B-0100"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Base R solution**

```
df1$id <- sub("^(.)0+?(.{4})$","\\1\\2", sub("-", "0000", toupper(df1$id)))
```

**tidyverse solution**

```
library(tidyverse)    
df1$id <- str_to_upper(df1$id) %>%
  str_replace("-","0000") %>%
  str_replace("^(.)0+?(.{4})$","\\1\\2")
```

**Output**

```
df1

#      id n
# 1 A0001 1
# 2 A0010 2
# 3 A0100 3
# 4 B0001 4
# 5 B0010 5
# 6 B0100 6
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c("A-1","A-10","A-100","b-1","b-10","b-100"),n=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```